# Xpath find child on the parent only if another child is present

Tags: html, xpath

So I have a web page where I would like to find button **SignUp** only if button **NameField** is present in the `div entire class`.

```
<div class="entire class">
    <div class = "upper class>
        <button class="NameField"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="lower class">
        <button class="SignUp"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I achieve that? I have tried the following:

```
$x("//div[@class='entire class']//button[@class='NameField'] and not(descendant::button[@class='SignUp']")

$x("//*[@class='upper class'] | [@class='SignUp']")

$x("//*[@class='SignUp'] | //body)[last()]")

$x("//div[//button[@class='SignUp'] and [//button[@class='NameField']]")
```

None of them seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Try below `XPath`:

```
//div[button[@class="NameField"]]/following-sibling::div/button[@class="SignUp"]

//div[@class="entire class" and div[button[@class="NameField"]]]/div/button[@class="SignUp"]
```

or simplified one:

```
//button[@class="NameField"]/following::button
```

Comment: So the first option doesn't return anything. The second option returns all SignUp buttons even in the div where NameField button is absent.

Comment: You mean there are more than one pair of `NameField`/`SignUp` buttons? Yes, in this case, second option is not acceptable. But first should work (works for me). Check whether provided `HTML` sample looks totally the same as real `HTML`- you might remove some important node while preparing this sample

Comment: @President, also try this one `//div[@class="entire class" and div[button[@class="NameField"]]]/div/button[@class="SignUp"]`